# Create Hash with multiple values, Ruby and Mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby, hash

I am using the mysql2 gem to connect to my database and pull out data. It's a simple query

```
statement = @db.prepare('SELECT * FROM my_table')
@result = statement.execute
```

This returns a `Mysql2::Result` object, I know to iterate through I do this

```
@result.each do |r|
  puts r
end
```

Which will give back in my case

```
[
  {"id"=>1,
  "name"=>"Standard",
  "label"=>"Standard",
  "amount"=>100,
  "created_at"=>2010-11-17 11:50:38 +0000,
  "updated_at"=>2010-11-17 11:50:38 +0000,
  "status"=>"active",
  "dataprofileid"=>"0",
  "groupid"=>1},
 {"id"=>2,
  "name"=>"Director Register",
  "label"=>"Director Register",
  "amount"=>150,
  "created_at"=>2010-11-17 11:51:11 +0000,
  "updated_at"=>2010-11-17 11:51:11 +0000,
  "status"=>"active",
  "dataprofileid"=>"18",
  "groupid"=>0}
]
```

From this I want to create a Hash that looks like

```
{ "Standard"=> { "id"=>1, "dataprofileid"=> 0 }}
```

So for each record use the `name` as the key, and then have further key/values inside. At the moment I have created a regular Hash with `name` as the key and the `id` as the value but am not sure on how to get to the next stage

```
@credit_ids = []
@credit_names = []
@credit_dataprof = []
  @result.each do |r|
    @credit_names << r['name']
    @credit_ids << r['id']
    @credit_dataprof << r['dataprofileid']
end
@credit_hash = Hash[@credit_names.zip @credit_ids]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. map() your array to the hashs that you actually want as values.
2. Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

This will allow you to get all the hashs by name, with the full hash following.

or I didn't get your question. :)

Comment: thanks, think i got there, posted an answer, unless theres a cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

I come across another answer on SO and come up with this which works, hopefully it helps someone else

```
h = Hash.new{|hsh, key| hsh[key] = {} }
@result.each do |r|
  h[r['name']].store 'id', r['id']
  h[r['name']].store 'dataprofileid', r['dataprofileid']
end
```

This then returns

```
{
  "Standard"=> { "id" => 1, "dataprofileid" => "0" },
   "CCJ" => { "id" => 5, "dataprofileid" => "20" }
   # Many more ommitted but you get the idea
}
```

Open for suggestions mind to improve this

Comment: or `result = hash.inject({}) do |output, input| output[input.first.name] = input.slice('id', 'dataprofileid'); output end` for a one loop / one liner.

Comment: ooooo nicely played @muichkine :-)

Comment: This only works if all your input hash have different names btw. (both your and my versions). otherwise you have to have your output hash values be arrays to which you push your value hashes.

Answer (score 0):

The naive:

```
@result.map{
  |h| {h["name"] => {"id" => h["id"], "dataprorileid" => h["dataprofileid"]}}
}
```

will give you:

```
[
  {"Standard"=>{"id"=>1, "dataprorileid"=>"0"}},
  {"Director Register"=>{"id"=>2, "dataprorileid"=>"18"}}
]
```

But if you want to respect the original structure (with the key-value pairs other than `"name"` retained), then:

```
@result.map{|h| k = h.dup.delete("name"); {k => h}}
```

will give you:

```
[
  {"Standard"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Standard", "label"=>"Standard", "amount"=>100, "created_at"=>2016-01-14 20:47:04 +0900, "updated_at"=>2016-01-14 20:47:04 +0900, "status"=>"active", "dataprofileid"=>"0", "groupid"=>1}},
  {"Director Register"=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"Director Register", "label"=>"Director Register", "amount"=>150, "created_at"=>2016-01-14 20:47:04 +0900, "updated_at"=>2016-01-14 20:47:04 +0900, "status"=>"active", "dataprofileid"=>"18", "groupid"=>0}}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@credit_ids = []
@credit_names = []
@credit_dataprof = []
@credit_hash = Hash.new()
  @result.each do |r|
    @credit_names = r['name']
    @credit_ids = r['id']
    @credit_dataprof = r['dataprofileid']

 @credit_hash  = @credit_hash.merge({@credit_names => {"id" => @credit_ids, "dataprofileid" => @credit_dataprof}})
end

 puts @credit_hash
```

produces:

```
{"Standard"=>{"id"=>1, "dataprofileid"=>"0"}, "Director Register"=>{"id"=>2, "dataprofileid"=>"18"}}
```